# Calculate amount between two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables one for incoming goods and inventory and another for the exit of products.

How do I do a select in mysql to return the amount available in stock without using PHP.

In the case would STOCK - OUTPUTS.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. `without using PHP`, why tag PHP? 2. Are you using some other server side langauge. 3. Where are you displaying or using this data? You could just query and output a CSV, no?

Comment: The code is more or less this: SELECT SUM(madeira_entrada.quantidade) AS total_entrada, SUM(madeira_saida.quantidade) AS total_saida, SUM(total_entrada-total_saida) AS total_estoque FROM tb_madeira_entrada AS madeira_entrada LEFT JOIN tb_madeira_saida AS madeira_saida ON madeira_saida.madeira = '$this->produtoID' WHERE madeira = '$this->produtoID'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM stock) - 
(SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM outputs) AS 'slo'
```

Comment: `SELECT (SELECT SUM(quantidade) FROM tb_madeira_entrada WHERE madeira = '$this->produtoID')-(SELECT SUM(quantidade) FROM tb_madeira_saida WHERE madeira = '$this->produtoID') AS estoque_disponivel` 

I did try it, but not work!

Comment: Is that written in a PHP file or what?